# Does Mac App Store accept application written in Python/Java/Ruby?

Tags: macos, app-store

Does Mac App Store accept application written in Python/Java/Ruby?

Comment: Java? No. The other two are unknown at this point.

Comment: @MattGreer Your comment is no longer correct. See my answer on this page. As of 2012-2013 (at least), the Mac App Store does admit Java-based apps.

Answer (score 18):

**The Good News**

Yes, you *can* submit a [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28software_platform%29) app to the Mac App Store. Not true in the past, but it is true at least as of now in 2013.

One example is the successful  [MoneyDance](http://www.Moneydance.com/) personal finance app currently [available for sale](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moneydance-personal-finance/id538911179?mt=12) in the Mac App Store.

**The Bad News**

Preparing and submitting your app is neither simple nor easy. You have to jump through some hoops.

- Your app cannot depend on Java being installed on the Mac. You must include a JRE ([Java Runtime Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Runtime_Environment)) within your Mac app.
- You must write a thin Objective-C wrapper around your Java app. The source code and examples/tutorials are available on the web.
- Like any other app, you must go through all hassle of the complicated build and deployment rigmarole with security restrictions Apple requires of any Mac App Store app.

**More Info**

- Two articles, [Take your Java application to the Mac App Store](http://www.intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/) and [Forking the OpenJDK for fun and profit](http://www.intransitione.com/blog/forking-jdk-for-fun-and-profit/), by [Marco Dinacci](http://intransitione.com/about.html). These articles may provide other useful information, but fortunately their discussion of forking the JDK is now outmoded. He and others have provided the needed patches now incorporated in the official releases.
- [How to Create a Mac OS X Installer for a Java Application (Updated for Mac OS X 10.8 — Mountain Lion)](http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/) by Dem Pilafian of Center Key Software.
- [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) (Oracle)
- [Submitting to the Mac App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/index.html) (Apple)

By the way, you can use both [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) and [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) in your app. JavaFX is now bundled with Java, at least as of [Java 7 Update 40](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/2008412) according to these [Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u40-relnotes-2004172.html#jfx-rn).

## Java 9

The newly released Java 9 should make this process of wrapping an app with a runtime even easier and better.

### Modules

Java 9 brings “modularization”, [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), where the approximately 5,000 classes bundled with a JVM are grouped into about a hundred chunks known as *modules*. You can include only the modules containing classes actually used by your particular app rather hauling along every library. If you don't use [JSON](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [CORBA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), then you need not include the JSON or CORBA related modules.

The new [*jlink*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282) tool does this work for you, to assemble and optimize a set of modules and their dependencies into a custom run-time image. As a bonus, some link-time optimization work is performed to make your app launch faster.

These features are supported on 64-bit macOS systems, along with other platforms.

### Native compiling

Java 9 also brings new support for native compiling, to build an app optimized for specific hardware. But this ability is experimental, and not yet ready for production use.

## Update, as of 2018

Oracle has [announced the end of web deployment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) technology, including [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start), the previously recommended avenue for desktop apps. So now, Oracle expects all Java apps to be delivered bundled with a JVM such as is done with the `jlink` tool mentioned above.

So, the process of wrapping an app with a Java runtime that was something of a rarity just for the Apple App Store is now mainstream. Oracle expects any Java-based desktop app to be installed this way.

Comment: Any changes in 2016?

Comment: @sinedsem See my edits regarding some changes for 2017, with the arrival of Java 9.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. Apple doesn't care what language your App is written in, but it cannot depend on or install anything outside of the binary you submit to Apple. The relevant guidelines are below:

```
2.14
Apps must be packaged and submitted using Apple's packaging technologies included in Xcode - no third party installers allowed
2.15
Apps must be self-contained, single application installation bundles, and cannot install code or resources in shared locations
2.16
Apps that download or install additional code or resources to add functionality or change their primary purpose will be rejected
```

So, while this means you can't depend on Ruby or Python, you could use a framework like MacRuby to build your app in Ruby and embed the Ruby interpreter. Speaking for MacRuby, apps have been successfully submitted to the Mac App Store this way.

Comment: Since python and ruby are pre-installed on OS X I am not sure why the above statements would prevent you from relying on them unless there is something else preventing there usage.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby ? Yes !
Apple already accepted one of my apps written in MacRuby.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Cocoa will allow you include code written in different languages (including Ruby and Python, but not Java I don't think).

Check the Apple SDK's for more info, but I believe (thanks to Cocoa) it's not a problem.

Comment: Incorrect about Java. Java apps *can* be submitted. See my answer on this page.

Comment: This post **should** be updated or deleted to reflect the current status. Java apps can be deployed onto the Mac App Store!

Answer (score 2):

For Python apps, I wrote a comprehensive article explaining how to build and submit such apps to the Mac App Store. It includes source code and build scripts for a barebones example app that I have successfully submitted.

- [Submitting a Python App to the Mac App Store](http://dafoster.net/articles/2014/06/24/submitting-a-python-app-to-the-mac-app-store/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=pymas)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly Java, if you bundle the Java application into a mac application.

Comment: is it possible with macOS Monterey & Xcode 13.. In 2022?