# Will java application be accepted on the new Mac App Store?

Tags: java, app-store

I heard Apple will accept only Objective C apps in the Mac App store.

Someone know if java app will be accepted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apple has said that apps that depend upon deprecated technologies, such as their internal java implementation, will not be allowed in the app store.  However, Apple has contributed much work to the OpenJDK project which includes an embeddable JRE that can be used to create a self-contained app bundle for a java application.

Apple employees have also hinted, if not stated explicitly on the Apple java-dev mailing list, that java apps using this embedded JRE will land on the right side of the "no deprecated technologies" rule.

[Update 2012.10.05] We now have proof that Apple approves of Java apps in the Mac App Store.  Our app, Moneydance (http://infinitekind.com/moneydance-appstore) has been bundled with the OpenJDK (with a few custom patches) and is now available for sale in the app store.  Marco Dinacci has posted a detailed instructions for how to bundle and build the apps here: http://intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/

Comment: For more links, see my answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997867/does-mac-app-store-accept-application-written-in-python-java-ruby/18807551#18807551

Answer (score 0):

No, apps on the app store appear to be limited to C, C++ or Objective-C only

See [here](http://www.engadget.com/2010/10/21/apples-mac-app-store-review-guidelines-posted-will-photoshop/) for a few more details

Comment: This is plain untrue, see other comments.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible! The trick is that software should be self-sufficient (e.g. not require preexisting Java installation)

[Ensemble](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ensemble/id557744983?mt=12) app built with Java FX is on the app store. [This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) details the steps necessary.