# GameCenter for Mac with Java

Tags: java, macos, game-center, mac-app-store

I am currently teaching a student on how to code a game in Java on a Mac. GameCenter is a service provided by Apple that lets one see their game stats on a leaderboard and lets them play online. **Does anyone know if it's possible to implement GameCenter in Java or if it's even possible to publish a Java app on the Mac App Store?**

Comment: Not without some JNI/JNA. You could start by looking at the [Game Centre for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/game-center/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Basics

You would need to translate ***parts*** of your Java application over to Objective-C, which is what OS X and iOS support.

Fortunately in the last couple of years there has been a decent amount of progress and attention in terms of tools, techniques, and methods that can help you do this. There's even an open-source tool/runtime that can take Java code and turn it into Objective-C:

**[J2ObjC](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/)**

It's fairly popular, and can probably set you in the right direction.

---

> EDIT: I've added the word **parts** above since it was apparently unclear to
>   [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque), and/or possibly anyone else who may have taken the word **translate** as having to re-write your entire app in objective-c.

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! I never knew that there were converters! Thanks for the info! I'd up vote this if I had enough reputation. Until then, please take this comment as my sincere thanks.

Comment: Or, you could look at using a cocoa bridge of some type, like [Rococoa](http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/)

Comment: @alexsmbaratti, You're welcome! — I'm glad it's helpful to you, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

### Java-Based Mac App

The [answer by l'L'l](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21210342/642706) is not entirely correct. You do **not** need to translate your Java code to Objective-C. You **can** ship a Java-based app in the Apple *Mac App Store*.

Apple changed their policies to now allow Java-based apps for sale in the **Mac** App Store. This applies only to Mac apps, as far as I know, not for iOS. There is no Java implementation released that runs on iOS as far as I know. Sun demonstrated a prototype once publicly, but never released anything for iOS afaik.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18807551/642706) to a similar question. The successful app [Moneydance](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moneydance-personal-finance/id367748818?mt=8) is an example, as noted on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7988104/642706).

### Nutshell

- You create a **thin Objective-C app** that wraps your Java app, using Xcode.
  Other people have provided templates for this minimal code.
- Your Mac app must **include a JVM** ([Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)).
  In other words, your Mac app *cannot* access a JVM that may already be installed on the user’s Mac.
- You may use **Swing or JavaFX** for presenting a user interface.
  Both Apple’s and Oracle’s implementations of Java ship with extensions to [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) for a Mac look and feel. The latest implementations from Oracle also include [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX).

Oracle provides [these instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) on how to package your app for the Mac App Store.

## GameCenter

I do not know the details of accessing GameCenter from the Java-based part of your game. You may need to write some Objective-C in order to interact with Apple's GameCenter libraries/framework.

As noted by MadProgrammer (comment on question), your Java code may interact with Objective-C code by using either:

- **JNI** – [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)
  Bundled with Java platform, by Oracle/Sun.
- **JNA** – [Java Native Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access)
  A third-party library. Becoming popular as a simpler alternative to JNI. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1556421/642706) for comparison of JNA to JNI.

---

## Xojo

By the way, another non-Objective-C platform for shipping apps in the Mac App Store is [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com/), formerly known as RealBasic. A very slick set of tools with a fully object-oriented programming language. Popular with both beginning programmers and professionals.

Comment: By "translate" I did not mean "re-write in it's entirety", so i've edited my answer to clarify. And are you saying that java applications on OS X or iOS wouldn't need at least some portions to be written in Objective-C or Objective C++? Just curious, since I was under the impression some of it needed to be if you're using the Apple frameworks. Also, thanks for adding the nice summary of techniques, good information definitely :)

Comment: @l'L'l No, you needn’t rewrite any of your Java code as far as I know. But note I've not yet shipped such an app yet, so I have no experience, only study. You just need the most basic of an Xcode project with just enough Objective-C code to launch the JVM and your classes. Other folks have provided that example code as I mentioned. Also, I revised my answer to make clear that only the *Mac* App Store allows Java apps, not the iOS app store.

Comment: @l'L'l As for reaching out to utilize Apple's Cocoa (or Carbon) libraries, yes then you'll need to write some Objective-C code and use JNI/JNA to interface with your Java code. But for many kinds of apps, the Java platform is complete. You have access to the file system, networking, collections, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), and all the other great Java libraries. Swing lets you build a normal-looking Mac-style user interface. And now JavaFX lets you build wilder-looking user interfaces.